# Remove subtitles from an AVI?

Tags: avi, subtitles

I got my hands on an old AVI.

When opened with VLC, it looks like there are two embedded SRT in the AVI header (possible?)

Can I remove them? (Yes, they are soft subs) Or can I clean the header? I tried with VirtualDub to do a direct copy of video and audio, but subs were left in the file (although it was 4 mb smaller)

Comment: See if [AVI-Mux GUI](http://www.alexander-noe.com/video/amg/) can do it (might need to use Compatibility Mode to get it to run on Vista+). If direct deletion of the SRTs is not possible, maybe you can demux the audio and video streams and just remux those back to a new AVI.